# Linux kill command before executing it

Tags: linux, centos, command

What I'm trying to do is to make sure the command isn't running before executing it (so it won't duplicate itself). I read that the && operator should work here because it should execute the second command only if the first command isn't outputting any errors, but in my case it doesn't execute the command. Let me demonstrate.

Let's assume the command is `./root/script 1 2 3`, what I'm trying to do is to run the following: `pkill -f './root/script 1 2 3' && ./root/script 1 2 3`.
But what ends up happening is that either the second command isn't being executed at all or that the pkill command is being executed after the second command therefore killing it as well. Either way I end up not having the command running at all.

Do you have any input regarding this matter? How would I make sure a command isn't already running before executing it?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: @Xorg: No, that is not true at all. The dot signifies current directory, not a hidden file. And the behavior when the process is not found is that no process is started.

Comment: @ tripleee..I realized this after I made this comment but i was a little skeptical why this command line is not working with the OP. :D

Answer (score 1):

`pkill` has an exit status of 1 if no processes matched. That means that if there is no instance of `./root/script 1 2 3` running, `pkill` comes back with a non-zero exit status that the shell considers false, and the command after the && is not executed.

You could catch this as follows:

```
(pkill -f './root/script 1 2 3' || [ $? -eq 1 ]) && ./root/script 1 2 3
```

`$?` is the exit status of the `pkill` call, so this tests if `pkill` returned 0 or 1 and runs `./root/script 1 2 3` in either of those cases.

Comment: This would very often work, but there is no guarantee. You might be unlucky enough so that one script has been killed, and another is just starting.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is true, but I don't think there's a way to handle that race condition reliably without help from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Killing a running script is not the nicest thing to do.
A lot of programs start by writing a `this_is_my_pid.tmp` file after checking it does not exist. When finished they remove the file.
When the file exists they check the pid in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but where should this file be created at?

Comment: When your app has it's own working dir taht is a nice place. Some choose /var/xxx or mostly /tmp.   
Try `grep -i pid /etc/init*/*`